# How to href to a local folder on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have `svg-icons` and `Bootstrap` folder in `wwwroot`.

And my html code to use SVG icon is:

```
<svg class="olymp-happy-face-icon"><use xlink:href="svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-happy-face-icon"></use></svg>
```

When I run my ASP.NET MVC project, I got console:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found
>   Location: https://localhost:44342/Home/svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg

How can I import or href to `svg-icons` folder to `ASP.NET MVC` like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css">

<svg class="olymp-menu-icon"><use xlink:href="svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-menu-icon"></use></svg>
```

Comment: It starts with ~/The base directory. example ~/Content/icons/svg-icons etc..

Comment: If I'm reading things right, you have 2 differing errors - `404` and `XML parsing error`.  Start with XML error - the 404/tilde `~` is only relevant in `Razor`, and you _don't have to use it_ **if you know your (relative) paths** (`~` is for convenience, that says "start from application root".  What exactly do you see when hitting the XML error?

Answer (score 1):

You need add ~ before svg url

```
<svg class="olymp-menu-icon">
 <use xlink:href="~/svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-menu-icon"></use></svg>
```

Comment: I tried this before but got console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`.
When I goto `https://localhost:44342/Home/svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg` I got 404 but I remove `Home/` it's work.